# Target dimension mismatch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to learn deep learning for a school project. I used ESNet as the network architecture and as of the moment, I am using a simple dataset (cats vs dogs) just to test how the architecture performs. I first saved my dataset in a separate file and later loaded it to my model. Since my dataset is a NumPy array, I converted it to tensors and then resized it. When trying to train, I got the following error:

RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 2

Based on the suggestions I found online, the error points out to my target not having the right shape. My input has the shape [batch_size, 3, 100, 100].
Based on this shape the output would have the shape [batch_size, 2, 104, 104] and thus the target should have the shape [batch_size, 104, 104] and contain values in [0, 1]. Yet, whenever i try to train in and try to print what shape my target's shape I got [batch_size, 2].

and this is my training code:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 10
EPOCHS = 1

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_x), BATCH_SIZE)): 
        batch_x = train_x[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 100, 100)
        batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]

        print(batch_y.shape)
      
        model.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(batch_x)
        print(outputs.shape)
        loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()    # Does the update

    print(f"Epoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")
```

I've tried every suggestion I found online but found no success. Can anyone help me out? Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the interpreter telling you where the RuntimeError occurs? We'll need more information, before we can help a stack trace would be perfect.

Comment: @NolanFaught the error occurs in:  loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y) sir

Comment: Edit your question to include this information and cut out irrelevant bits of code. Consult the guide at our [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question further, and welcome to the community!

Comment: @NolanFaught I tried to edit my question sir. I hope it is much clearer this time